# Error setting timeout with javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.1

Tags: java, jax-rs, rest

I'm working in set timeout to a restApi Client via jax ws rs, i made it in this way

```
ClientBuilder clientBuilder = ClientBuilder.newBuilder();
clientBuilder.connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
clientBuilder.readTimeout(12, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
Client client = clientBuilder.build();
```

But, this stills throwing this exception and i don't have any clue of the reason

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.connectTimeout(JLjava/util/concurrent/TimeUnit;)Ljavax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder;
at weblogicrestfulapi.consumeRFApi.requestRestApi(consumeRFApi.java:74)
    at weblogicrestfulapi.consumeRFApi.readResponseRestApi(consumeRFApi.java:96)
    at weblogicrestfulapi.main.main(main.java:90)
C:\Users\medinajaim\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
```

I hope somebody can help me with this, thank you!

Comment: You should paste the whole exception but this looks like a dependency issue where you are not providing a implementation.

Comment: Added, but there's none value info

Comment: Check your dependency tree and make sure you aren't pulling in a different JAX-RS version somewhere.

Comment: How can i get the correct dependency tree?

Comment: Use mvn dependency:tree to see all the dependencies and transitive dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If somebody comes choosing an answer for this, my solution was based in Deadron and Paul comments, i found this [link](https://dzone.com/articles/jersey-client-dependencies-for-jax-rs-21) who resolves the dependencies of javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.1 if you are outside of an enterprise container

For me, it works only addings this two dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.26</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
    <version>2.26</version>
</dependency>
```